# Exploding database content with linebreaks in PHP doesn't create array

Tags: php, line-breaks

I've stored some values in my database which have linebreaks.

Wanting to transform those contents into an array, I did it like this:

```
$arr = explode($rs[data],"\n");
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Any ideas as to what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters of your [**`explode()`**](http://www.php.net/explode) call are inverted :

- The first parameter should be the delimiter -- which will be used to explode the string
- And the second parameter should be the string -- which will be exploded.

So, you should use :

```
$arr = explode("\n", $rs[data]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = explode("\n",$rs[data]);
```

You are passing parameters wrongly try above